# DLFileEntry size in the memory

Tags: java, memory, liferay, portlet

Can someone tell me what is the size of a DLFileEntry record in the memory? I'm holding a List of DLFileEntries and I want to be just sure that my portlet won't have a memory issue after deploying it on a server, operating with a large number of records. Or can someone give me a guide how to obtain this information? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a quick test or [look at the source](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/impl/DLFileEntryImpl.java#L409) and identify members. You're probably referring to the binary data, which is [not directly stored](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/impl/DLFileEntryImpl.java#L80) in an object of this class. However, it will most likely be cached, so yes, there's some memory overhead. Do you actually need the binary data or will you just hold placeholders without accessing the binary data for all documents that you're holding in memory?

(Note: The source code I'm linking is the current master branch - check the version that you're actually using and figure out if something changed. As you don't give the version, I'll leave this task for yourself. Also, you might want to check the superclasses (I didn't find anything suspicious in master)

Comment: What I'm actually doing is a metadata searcher for this entries. So I need to obtain author's name, creating date, etc.. Also dynamic structures as a metadata can be made in Liferay, so I need to check these for each entry. I don't quite understand if I need only placeholders when I want to access this fields of FileEntry and what’s behind implementation of List<DLFileEntry> and how much memory will it use. I'll try to understand and use the links in your answer, hopefully I will get some answer.

Comment: I've just realized this part of code, this method - getFileAsStream, going to try it. Thank you :) .